# Resizing ubuntu partion can't access unlocated space

Tags: partitioning

[image]

As you can seen in the screenshot I have unlocated space of 13.78Gb. I would like to add this to my Ubuntu partition /dev/sda5. How can I do this ? Since it is not next to the partition, I can't. Do i first have to merge this with dev/sda3 en then again seperate it from it and put it behind it ?

Comment: It's not *exactly* the same, but see [this question/answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/262221/partitioning-moving-an-extended-partition-containing-and-swap-to-extend-ano) to help you understand what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The partition you are trying to manipulate is the one which has OS on it. and you can't perform any changes on a drive that is mounted.
Download the GParted .ISO image. Follow the instructions here-
(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) to burn the .ISO image to CD.This is a bootable CD. Shutdown and boot with the Gparted CD. At this moment there is no operation system running so you can make your partitions.

Comment: I am already doing that. I work from the live cd.

Answer (score 0):

`sda5` is in an extended partition called `sda4`, so what you have to do is:

1. Back-up all partitions
2. move `sda3` to the left
3. Apply changes and go to sleep (you! Not the computer as this will take a lot of time)
4. Wake up, extend `sda4` to the left
5. Apply changes
6. Extend `sda5` to the left
7. Apply changes and go work
8. go to sleep
9. Wake up and everything will be done

While it's resizing: ensure the computer doesn't get bumped, it's power doesn't get interrupted, no beer gets spilled over it, ...